# Third level category in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, categories, opencart2.x

My **category** structure is:

```
Electronics
    -TV
       --LG
       --ONIDA
    -Fridge
       --Whirlpool
       --Videocon
    -Music Player
       --Sony
       --LG
Furniture
    -Wooden
       --Chair
       --Bed
    -Metal
       --Chair
```

Here my **main categories** are `Electronics, Furniture`; **Subcategories** are `TV, Fridge etc` and **sub-subcategories** are `LG, Onida etc`. That is I have `3 level categories.`
I have to display these in `main navigation menu in Opencart`.

But in `Opencart` `main category and sub categories` are only displayed. `Third level category` are not displayed.

So **how I display the third level category.** Here I am attaching a image, that tell my requirement more clear.
[image]

My **Opencart version** is **2.0.3.1**

**EDIT**

Here is the code for displaying the category menu.

> catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\header.tpl

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-inner">
          <?php foreach (array_chunk($category['children'], ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column'])) as $children) { ?>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <?php foreach ($children as $child) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="see-all"><?php echo $text_all; ?> <?php echo $category['name']; ?></a> </div>
    </li>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Where is your code where you show these categories?

Comment: in `opencart` there only provision for displaying `two level category`. I don't know which page/pages to change to make it working. If any one working with `Opencart` can help me..

Comment: @AlanMachado, I added the code. Please check...

Answer (score 1):

> Note : It's not recommended to make the direct changes in the core
>   files. You can make the vqmod for the same changes. changes given here
>   are tested in the default template, it might be different in other
>   custom theme.

(1) Open file **catalog/controller/common/header.php** and search for

```
$children_data = array();
```

and write below code **after it**

```
$children_lv3_data = array();
```

2) In **same file** Replace

```
$children_data[] = array(
                        'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                        'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
                    );
```

with below code

```
$children_lv3 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($child['category_id']);

if($children_lv3)
{    

    foreach ($children_lv3 as $child_lv3) 
    {
        $filter_data_lv3 = array(
        'filter_category_id'  => $child_lv3['category_id'],
        'filter_sub_category' => true
        );

        $children_lv3_data[] = array(
        'category_id' => $child_lv3['category_id'],
        'name'  => $child_lv3['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data_lv3) . ')' : ''),
        'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'] . '_' . $child_lv3['category_id'])
        );
    }

    $children_data[] = array(
            'children_lv3' => $children_lv3_data,
    'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
    );

}

else
{

    $children_data[] = array(
'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
    );
}
```

3) Open file **catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl** and search for

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a></li>
```

and put below code after it

```
<?php if(isset($child['children_lv3']) && count($child['children_lv3'])>0){ ?>
                            <ul> 
                               <?php foreach ($child['children_lv3'] as $child_lv3) { ?>
                               <li><a href="<?php echo $child_lv3['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child_lv3['name']; ?></a></li>
                                <?php  } ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: after a long search and research I got the solution.However I will try your answer..thanks and +1 for your quick answer...And it is very useful..